# Hadoop error - Unable to calculate input splits: need to login

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

I am trying out Hadoop to apply Map Reduce in my data, the sample [in this link](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-hadoop/) works fine when I configure local mongo collection for the properly `mongo.input.uri`.

But when I configure a remote mongo collection as shown below,

```
  <property>
    <name>mongo.input.uri</name>
    <value>mongodb://username:password@remote_mongodb_ip:27017/input_collection</value>
  </property>
```

I get the below error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to calculate input splits: need to login
```

The weirdest part is, the sample works fine if I configure local mongo db collection for
input table and remote mongo db collection for output table using the same above syntax format.

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: What's that `$` doing there?

Comment: woops.. thats a typo..
I have update the question..

Comment: Well, can you access mongo through this uri with `mongo` console client? I bet something's wrong with authentication (as setting up authentication ins Mongo is very inconvenient).

Comment: I tried to access the db via `mongo` client using ` `mongo remote_mongo_ip:27017/database_name -u "username" -p "password"`.. but its showing the below error when running `show dbs` `JavaScript execution failed: listDatabases failed:{ "errmsg" : "need to login", "ok" : 0 } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L46`
`
I think this is linked with the error i get when running hadoop job.. but not sure what is causing the issue.

Comment: I found since `show dbs` command is kind of admin command, it will not run when connecting for a single db. When i run the command `show collections`, its working.

Yes, i can able to connect to my remote mongo db using mongo client..

Comment: Well, that's exactly the same error ;). Honestly, I almost went crazy when I was setting up authentication in Mongo.

Comment: Right, but make sure that those operations performed by Hadoop do work from `mongo` shell.

Answer (score 2):

The splitVector command is required to split non-sharded collections, and it requires admin credentials.

There are a few solutions:

- If the collection is small and you can deal without the parallelism of multiple splits, you can turn off input splitting and deal with the whole collection at once in a single split, by setting mongo.input.split.create_input_splits to false.
- If you can shard the collection, the chunk ranges on the shards are used as split boundaries. Then the splitVector command is no longer needed, and all thats required is read permission on the chunks collection.

Comment: actually when I set the `mongo.input.split.create_input_splits = false`, the map reduce itself is not running, when I set this to `true`, it shows `Unable to calculate input splits`. Also my collection has much data, so I cannot go with the first option.